# is it possible to store the document edit history when using yjs as the collaboarate tool

Tags: yjs

I am using the yjs as the collaborate tool, I was wonder is it possible to store the document edit history and restore the specify location? I have read the official document https://docs.yjs.dev/ and did not mention how to store the edit version history and restore the history version docuemnt.

Comment: research revauled: [
Versioning yDocs for storage on a server (yjds.dev)](https://discuss.yjs.dev/t/versioning-ydocs-for-storage-on-a-server/109) which has a link to: [https://github.com/yjs/yjs-demos/tree/main/prosemirror-versions#prosemirror--versions-demo](https://github.com/yjs/yjs-demos/tree/main/prosemirror-versions) which says: "_In this variation of the ProseMirror demo, we allow you to create versions and render the differences and highlight the changes by a unique user-color._"   Does this help ?

Comment: that look like what I want, I will tried this script

Comment: I am using y-codemirror.next, seems did not add the version history feature.

Comment: Then some more research is needed.  The link is did send was one of the first results from https://www.google.com/search?q=yjs+versioning